# How to call a method with output parameters in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, wmi, remote-registry

I'm working on a script to get started in [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell). I'm trying to convert a [working VBScript script](http://www.visualbasicscript.com/m_28529/tm.htm) that enumerates mapped network drives on a remote Windows computer.

One of the tasks is to use remote [WMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation) to read the registry and find the process owner of explorer.exe in order to determine who is logged in. This seems easy enough going by [this guide](http://myitforum.com/cs2/blogs/scassells/archive/2008/10/01/powershell-wmi-wql-queries-made-easy-for-remote-wmi-especially-for-sms-2003-or-configmgr-2007.aspx).

However, the WMI method I need to call is [GetOwner() from Win32_Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390460(VS.85).aspx), which requires two output parameters to store its return value.

How can I call a method with output parameters? When I try to give it two strings, I get the error: `Cannot find an overload for "GetOwner" and the argument count: "2".`. The MSDN page says there are two parameters, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Using the `[ref]` modifier:

```
SomeMethod( [ref] $a );
```

Notable blog entries

- [http://geekswithblogs.net/Lance/archive/2009/01/14/pass-by-reference-parameters-in-powershell.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20200923105310/http://geekswithblogs.net/Lance/archive/2009/01/14/pass-by-reference-parameters-in-powershell.aspx)
- http://weblogs.asp.net/soever/archive/2009/03/26/powershell-return-values-from-a-function-through-reference-parameters.aspx

Comment: And call it like this     `$YouWillNeedTheParens = SomeMethod -a:([ref]$newVar)`

Answer (score 12):

```
$explorer = gwmi Win32_Process -computerName computerName -filter "Name='explorer.exe' and SessionID=0"   
$explorer.GetOwner() | select user,domain
```

Comment: I'd give you doublevotes if I could.  This is a better approach, but unfortunately doesn't match the main question so I kinda can't assign this as the accepted answer.

Comment: I may be missing something but the method signature doesn't show the overload you mentioned:

PS > $explorer.GetOwner.OverloadDefinitions
System.Management.ManagementBaseObject GetOwner()

Comment: You're using a different method.  I don't really see why, or how I would've known, that the Win32_Process doc shows two output parameters, but via Powershell it accepts none.  Does Powershell simply redirect output parameters as output sets?