# How to call a .net method with an output parameter?

Tags: .net, powershell, out

I just want to call the **GenerateScript** method of [Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom.Sql.Sql100ScriptGenerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd195523.aspx) from PowerShell.

```
#C

public void GenerateScript(
    IScriptFragment scriptFragment,
    out string script
)
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821744/how-to-call-method-with-output-parameters-in-powershell), but I do not get it to work

```
$sg = new-object  Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom.Sql.Sql100ScriptGenerator

$sql = 'select * from PowerShell'

$out = ''
$sg.GenerateScript($sql, [ref] $out)

$out
```

this gives

```
Cannot find an overload for "GenerateScript" and the argument count: "2".
At line:6 char:19
+ $sg.GenerateScript <<<< ($sql, [ref] $out)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

**Edit:**

Current version is

```
$sql = 'select * from PowerShell'

$sr = new-Object System.IO.StringReader($sql)

$sg =     new-object Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom.Sql.Sql100ScriptGenerator
$parser = new-object Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom.Sql.TSQL100parser($true)

$errors = ''
$fragment = $parser.Parse($sr,([ref]$errors))

$out = ''
$sg.GenerateScript($fragment,([ref][string]$out))

$out
```

But I get an error in line

```
$fragment = $parser.Parse($sr,([ref]$errors))



Cannot find an overload for "Parse" and the argument count: "2".
At line:11 char:26
+ $fragment = $parser.Parse <<<< ($sr,([ref]$errors))
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

I'm trying to convert

```
    IList<ParseError> errors;

    using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(inputScript))
    {
        fragment = parser.Parse(sr, out errors);
    }
```

**Edit:**

OK this works:

```
$sql = @'
select * from PowerShell -- a comment
where psRefnr = 1
'@
$options = new-object Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom.Sql.SqlScriptGeneratorOptions

$sr = new-Object System.IO.StringReader($sql)

$sg =     new-object Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom.Sql.Sql100ScriptGenerator($options)
$parser = new-object Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom.Sql.TSQL100parser($true)

$errors = $null
$fragment = $parser.Parse($sr,([ref]$errors))

$out = $null
$sg.GenerateScript($fragment,([ref]$out))

$out
```

and generates ( it removes the comment as intended )

```
SELECT *
FROM   PowerShell
WHERE  psRefnr = 1;
```

Comment: "but I do not get it to work": Please expand: are you getting an error/warning? Is the behaviour you're getting not what you expect: what do you expect, and what are you getting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call method with output parameters in Powershell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821744/how-to-call-method-with-output-parameters-in-powershell)

Comment: The question there is WMI related and the answer doesn't apply.

Comment: You are again passing the wrong type of parameter. You are passing a string for $errors to Parse, when it expects a IList<ParseError>.

Comment: Forgot to mention, try setting $errors to $null. By setting it to '' you are making it a string.

Comment: Please can someone add a tag sql-parser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your issue is with your first parameter, which should be a IScriptFragment. You are passing a string.

You would need to pass something that derives from [TSqlFragment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.data.schema.scriptdom.sql.tsqlfragment.aspx). Using something like the [TSql100Parser.ParseStatementList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.data.schema.scriptdom.sql.tsql100parser.parsestatementlist.aspx) method, you will get a list of fragments.

EDIT: This [blog post](http://wiki.poshcode.org/FAQ/Problems_and_Gotchas/%5Bout%5D_Parameters_and_Generic_Parameters) has a similar issue to your second error.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure how this works with Powershell, but in normal C# you need to call an out parameter with the keyword "out" instead of the "ref" you have.  Sorry if this is off base, but figured it might help.

Comment: in powershell, [ref] covers both c#'s out and ref.