# How to wire up SharpSvn.SvnUpdateResult in powershell

Tags: powershell, sharpsvn

Trying to automate my morning ritual of updating multiple subversion working copies by using a powershell script. The svn [update](http://docs.sharpsvn.net/current/html/M_SharpSvn_SvnClient_Update_7.htm) is working fine, but it would nice to hook into the [SvnUpdateResult](http://docs.sharpsvn.net/current/html/M_SharpSvn_SvnUpdateResult__ctor.htm) to show changes or any conflicts.

I've got as far as specifying the output parameter for the update result, but am not sure how to overcome the ambiguous overloads exception? I am already specifying the parameter types:

```
try {
    Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\SharpSVN\SharpSvn.dll"
}
catch [System.BadImageFormatException] {
    Write-Host "LFMF: You're probably using 32bit SharpSVN.dll in 64bit powershell ;-)"
}
$paths = @("Project-Trunk", "Project-Branch");
$currentPath = (Get-Location).Path
$svnClient = New-Object SharpSvn.SvnClient
foreach ($path in $paths) {
    Write-Host "Updating" $path
    $svnLocalPath = Join-Path $currentPath $path;
    # Throws: Multiple ambiguous overloads found for "Update" and the argument count: "2".
    $svnClient.Update([string]$svnLocalPath, [ref][SharpSvn.SvnUpdateResult]$result)
}
```

I appreciate I could just use svn client or tortoiseproc, but I'm trying to learn more about powershell.

Answer (score 1):

The result argument is a C# out argument, not a ref argument. (On the IL level an output argument is a ref argument, but I would guess that powershell handles it differently)

If output arguments are a problem it is also possible to get the same information from the notification handler.

Comment: Thanks Bert, I'll have a look at the notification handler. You're correct, powershell handles `out` using `[ref]`, see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5276700/44540