# Call generic method with 'out' parameter

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a 'SourceClass' class with the simple C# method:

```
public bool TryGetSection<T>(out T result) where T : class, new()
{ //do something and return true/false }
```

and I'd like to execute it from powershell code.

```
$_config = New-Object [SourceClass]
$method = [SourceClass].GetMethod("TryGetSection")
$genericMethod = $method.MakeGenericMethod([AuthenticationProviderTypeConfig])
$authenticationProviderTypeConfig = New-Object AuthenticationProviderTypeConfig
$genericMethod.Invoke($_config, $authenticationProviderTypeConfig)
$authenticationProviderType = $authenticationProviderTypeConfig.Type
```

After execution, I'm expecting that the $authenticationProviderType will be filled, but it isn't. I'm just getting an empty string. I suppose I miss something.
Is it possible to call generic method that has 'out' parameter? 
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call method with output parameters in Powershell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821744/how-to-call-method-with-output-parameters-in-powershell)

Comment: @Duncan, it isn't a duplicate, because my question is about how to execute a method that is generic and has 'out' parameter.